# How to display div for first page using CSS or velocity

Tags: html, css, velocity

I have a project that uses a velocity template (CSS and HTML), and renders a PDF file from it.  So it's not really a browser.  Anyway there is a DIV element that I want to appear on only the first page header, and not the second page header.  I can't seem to get it to work; i can get the page #, but i think velocity does it's rendering before the page number is displayed.  If I can get the page number into a variable somehow I'm golden.  Can't seem to get it though.

This displays the current page number.

```
<span id="pagenumber"/>
```

I've tried things like this but no soap.

```
set( $page = <span id='pagenumber'/> )
set ( $visible = "")
if ( !($page == "1") )  ## also tried if $page == 1
  set ( $visible = " visibility:hidden")
end

Page is $page <br />
Visible is $visible <br />
```

The $page variable does display 1 for the first page, but I don't think its really evaluated during velocitys rendering, it's basically just HTML string.

I'm not sure if I can use JS or not, probably not (but could try it).

Edit:

This does work in the CSS but its only for page information, not sure if I can nest a DIV element.

```
@page :first {
    margin-top: 5in;     /* Top margin on first page 10cm */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you have to use a `#foreach` statement to populate the output for each page, then target the first page by using `$velocityCount` to count the pages (`$velocityCount` starts the count at 1... if you want it to start at 0, use `$foreach.index`) and an `#if` statement to tell it to only set the visibility if it's == 1.

Something like...

```
#foreach($page in $pages)  
    #set($pageNum = $velocityCount )
    #if ($pageNum == 1)
        #set ($hidden = 'visibility:hidden;')
    #else
        #set ($hidden = '')
    #end

    <span id="${pageNum.value}" style="${hidden}">
#end
```